# Could not load file or assembly 'Facebook.Unity.Canvas'

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm using facebook sdk 7.18.0 with Unity.

[image: build settings]
When I `Build And Run`, it opens in a browser window and this error is shown.

```
FileNotFoundExceptin: Could not load file or assembly 'Facebook.Unity.Canvas' or one of its dependencies
```

[image: error]

But when I run the unity project by clicking the `Play` button, it works fine.

Is this because, Facebook sdk for unity doesn't support running in the browser?

Appreciate any help to resolve this issue.